# how to perform a matrix calculation (eg covariance matrix) for different levels of factor variable

Tags: r, matrix

I have the following simplified problem:

```
temp <- matrix(rnorm(900), ncol = 3)
lev <- as.factor(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 100))
dfr <- data.frame(lev = lev, temp = temp)
```

I wanted to calcualte the variance-covariance matrices for each of the three levels. How do I do this efficiently?

Many thanks for taking the time to read (and hopefully answer) my question!

Comment: Does this do what you want? `lapply(split(dfr, dfr$lev), function(x) cov(x[, -1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found the solution:

```
lapply(split(dfr, dfr$lev), function(x) var(x[,-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dfr)[, as.list(var(.SD)), lev]
```

Or using `by` from `base R`

```
by(dfr[-1], list(dfr[,1]), FUN = var)
```

Comment: But the formatting is harder to follow for a larger matrix. Thanks though!

Comment: @user3236841  So you want a `list` of matrices?  I was not sure about the format of the expected output